# Listening Test on Reverb

Tags: youtube

Some fun for those of you who are bored.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yT5LOtQSSn8&feature=youtu.be

They claim that the recording is live and no effects were added in. I'm not convinced. What do you guys think? Is this all the room, or has it been mixed?

Comment: I'm in half a mind to send them a link to our comments. Hahaha... So many gimmicks they employ these days for internet fame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artificial Reverb.  There is a single microphone, yet there is stereo image.  If the microphone were stereo (which I am sure it isn't) then there voices would be naturally panned in that image as they are on either side of it, but their voices are in the center.

Comment: The mic is a Rode NT-1A which is mono

Answer (score 1):

I bet they just fired up Garage Band or something similar for the audio recording.  Depending on what type of session you want, it'll use a predefined channel strip with verb, etc...

In fact, the default "Female Basic" channel on a new "Voice" session sounds remarkably similar :)

If your using a person as a mic stand, you're probably not checking the not-displayed-by-default channel strip settings for effects.  Also, by default, the recorded signal is not played out during recording.  They wouldn't have heard the 'echo' until playback.  Easy enough to make that mistake if you don't live and breathe this stuff.

Good on 'em for making music!  The tools should come second anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A room like that (what I assume to be a bedroom of some description) simply isn't big enough to have a tail that long.  Even bare walls like that would only give a tight flutter, something akin to a slap-back delay but limited to 1-2k and up.  Ugly.

Judging by the balance between voice/verb it has to have been added, from that kind of perspective the room would have to be... um... very large.

Answer (score 0):

listen to the voice at 2:40 then forward to 3:08, just before the "yay". sounds different..no?

Answer (score 0):

Artificial reverb.

Answer (score 0):

Good singing, though.

They claim it's the room?

Listen to the artificial-sounding zings on the tails of sibilance and hard consonants like Ks and Ts. That's at least a 2.0 if not longer added artificial verb and they're tightly up against a wall which makes me think it's their bedroom.

I totally agree with Iain and Mike. It's a mono mic...

But hey, all we have is the compressed audio of You-Tube to listen to. Also, they are bumping the Rode mic in frame like a punching bag and it doesn't make any noise. Perhaps there is a nice stereo pair of Senn or Schoeps behind the camera?

And what's the point in claiming it's unedited after they put reverb on it? I don't get why that's such a big deal that they put it in their description...

The world will never know...

Comment: Haha you're right. A friend of mine was actually the one that asked me about it and I thought it might be a bit of fun for everyone. They are quite cute though.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, the camera never does a 360 pan around.  For all we know there could be a gothic cathedral on the other side of that mic.

Comment: hahahaha... that answer rocks my socks off.

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the mic during the recording it waves around as if someone is holding it just off camera - The guitar sounds like it was mic'd seperately, as everyone has mentioned already there is a stereo image and reverb. And to my ears there is different reverb on the guitar than on the vox. It may well have been an un-edited but it certainly wasn't recorded in that space with that gear. But if it was recorded there and then and we are all totally wrong then thumbs up to them;)

Comment: Someone IS holding it, they say so in the description. Which means that there would have been handling noise, which there isn't.

Comment: I highly doubt they would ADR the whole thing, though.